# Coloring with a two color scale in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, colors, linear-gradients

I have an `input` element whose value is a number between 0 and 100. I am attempting to style the element via a two-color scale, taking its value as the input.

I am planning on making a simple gradient:

- When the number is 100, the element's background color is green `#00ff00`
- When the number is 0, it is red `#ff0000`
- When the number is 50, it displays a yellow color `#ffff00`

The in-between values should be colored according to the scale.

I have tried using an `if` statement in JavaScript, but that fails to create a gradient, as there is a hard border between red, yellow, and green (sans gradient). See the code below:

```js
var x = 0;

function color() {
    x = document.getElementById("color").value;
    console.log(x);

    if (x > 50) {
        document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
    }
    else if (x == 50) {
        document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="color();">Run</button>
<input type="number" id='color' value=50></input>
<!-- The input is not disabled for value debugging. -->
```

Is there concise way to perform this task?

Comment: As SO isn't a code writing service, you should post the code that you have written to try and solve this problem.

Comment: I have just done that, although I am very confused on what to do with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the optimal way to create a 2 color scale that uses vibrant, hexadecimal colors:

```js
var colval = 0;
var R = 0;
var G = 0;
var B = 0;

function check() {

  c = document.getElementById("color");
  x = c.value;

  if (x > 50) {

    R = Math.round(-0.051 * x ** 2 + 2.55 * x + 255);
    G = 255;

  } else if (x < 50) {

    R = 255;
    G = Math.round(-0.051 * x ** 2 + 7.65 * x + 0);

  } else {

    R = 255;
    G = 255;

  }

  B = 0;

  colval = "#" + R.toString(16) + G.toString(16) + "00";
  c.style.background = colval;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="color" min="0" max="100" value="0" onkeyup="check()">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const updateColor = (target) => {
    const value = target.value;
    //#00ff00 100
    //#ffff00 50
    //#ff0000 0
    const R = Math.round((255 / 50) * (value < 50 ? 50 : 100 - value)).toString(16)
    const G = Math.round((255 / 50) * (value > 50 ? 50 : value)).toString(16)
    const twoDigit = (d) => ("0" + d).slice(-2);
    const nextColor = '#' + twoDigit(R) + twoDigit(G) + '00';
    target.style.background = nextColor

  }
  document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('change', (e) => updateColor(e.target));
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    updateColor(document.getElementById('color'))
  });
```

```html
<html>

<body>
   <input type="number" id="color" min="0" max="100" value="0">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In my local computer, it is initialized background color with "Red".
I am afraid it isn't working in snippet mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html Range input for this purpose and Use javascript for getting its value. Like:

```
<input id="myId" type="range" min="0" max="100">
```

Use Javascript to get its value by using its ID. Use a Javascript function. Either call it using a button or add onchange event.

You are just missing a style property...
just do this

```
document.getElementById("color").style.background = "Any Color";
```

or if you want to change text color then

```
document.getElementById("color").style.color = "Any Color";
```

Here I wrote full code for your problem:-

```
<input type="number" id="color" min="0" max="100" onkeyup="check()">
<script>
    function check(){
        c = document.getElementById("color");
        x = c.value;
        if(x==0)
            c.style.background="Red";
        else if(x==50)
            c.style.background = "Yellow";
        else
            c.style.background = "Green";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So, what is the code for the `onchange` event or function?

Comment: I tried this code. Instead of displaying a gradient (orange at 25, red at 0, green at 100), the script just makes it red if `x = 0`, yellow if `x = 50`, and if `x` is something else, then the color of the input is green, no matter what. Is this a mistake?